# Calculation in django models within certain field of certain item type

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a table which has a field called first_year_estimate_total and second_year_estimate_total
which needs calculation. The calculation is done with all items first_year_estimate and second_year_estimate based on the category(land_capital_items_type)

```
class LandCapital(models.Model):
    land_capital_items_type = models.ForeignKey(
        LandCapitalItem, blank=True, null=True, related_name='land_capital')
    land_item = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    first_year_estimate = models.DecimalField(
        decimal_places=2, max_digits=20, default=100.00)
    second_year_estimate = models.DecimalField(
        decimal_places=2, max_digits=20, default=100.00)
    first_year_estimate_total = models.DecimalField(
        decimal_places=2, max_digits=20, default=100.00)
    second_year_estimate_total = models.DecimalField(
        decimal_places=2, max_digits=20, default=100.00)
```

Here first_year_estimate and second_year_estimate has to be filled by the user but 
first_year_estimate_total and second_year_estimate_total should be based on the calculation.

For example if I have the following data

land_capital_items_type with item1

```
CapitalItem1(land_capital_items_type)
item1 100 200
item2 500 700 

CapitalItem2(land_capital_items_type) 
item1 400 200
item2 600 300
```

Now the first_year_estimate_total of CapitalItem1 should be 600(100 of item1 and 500 of item2 first_year_estimate) and second_year_estimate_total of CapitalItem1 should be 900(200 of item1 and 700 of item2 second_year_estimate)

Similarly with CapitalItem2

I tried to do the following

```
LandCapital.objects.aggregate(Sum('first_year_estimate'))
```

but this does the sum of all items first_year_estimate and I want based on the category with an ability to get in the queryset

How can I do it so?

Comment: Do you want to calculate after a user fill the `first_year_estimate and second_year_estimate ` ?

Comment: yup but don't know the best scenario on when to fill . I think after filling will be fine because at first the total will be 0

Comment: You can do this in your `views.py`




    `objects = LandCapital.objects.all()
     sum = 0
     for object in objects:
        sum = object.first_year_estimate+ object.second_year_estimate
`

Comment: replace `sum` with `object.first_year_estimate_total`

Comment: I am using rest framework so I got confused on where to do. Also the problem is I want to calculated the sum based on the category not sum of all first_year_estimate

Comment: I guess rather than doing `objects = LandCapital.objects.all()` you can filter objects based on your `category`. Something like this
`objects = LandCapital.objects.filter(land_capital_items_type='request.the_input_ you_are_taking') `

Comment: It's great that you are using Sum, since it will perform better, rather than plain python code. You are missing one point: before aggregation you should filter queryset by type and then aggregate ->  LandCapital.objects.filter(<filter logic here>).aggregate(Sum('first_year_estimate'))